# How to structure cloud storage rules to allow getBlob but not getDownloadUrl

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-security

In a social media app where users can see posts from other users, a user may decide to block another user, or decide to make their profile private, and therefore we don't want any data to be retrievable once the user has been blocked (a public access token is therefore a no no).

From my understanding, one must disallow reads on a file in order to stop users from being able to access the public access token. How then would a user be able to use getBlob() on a path? Is there a database rule that would handle this, if we allow reads, then users could call the getDownloadUrl method when in a non-blocked state, and then use this in the future if blocked.

I understand that a user could save a file they view to their device, but this is clearly out of our control. We want to control what we can control.

Is this possible?

Thanks.